# Deserialize is not implemented

Tags: rust

So I'm learning how to build a REST API with Rust. I keep getting an error when trying to implement the following line:

```
 #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
  pub struct Config {
      pub pg: deadpool_postgres::Config,
      pub server: ServerConfig,
}
```

And this is the error code I'm getting:

```
 error[E0277]: the trait bound `deadpool_postgres::Config:
 config::_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
```

Here are my dependencies in Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
actix-rt = "2.3.0"
actix-web = "3.3.2"
serde = "1.0.130"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
config = "0.11.0"
tokio-pg-mapper = "0.2.0"
tokio-pg-mapper-derive = "0.2.0"
deadpool-postgres = "0.10.0"
tokio-postgres = "0.7.3"
```

I'm new to Rust and I'm not exactly sure what the error means or what to do to fix it. I'm implementing deadpool_postgres just like how it is in the docs, except in my file I'm trying to pull the database variables from a dotenv file. Here's the complete file:

```
use::config::ConfigError;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub pg: deadpool_postgres::Config,
    pub server: ServerConfig,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct ServerConfig {
    pub host: String,
    pub port: i32
}

impl Config {
    pub fn from_env() -> Result<Self, ConfigError> {
        let mut cfg = config::Config::new();
        cfg.merge(config::Environment::new())?;
        cfg.try_into()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler tells you the `deadpool_postgres::Config` struct doesn't implement `Deserialize`.

You need to enable the "serde" [feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) in your Cargo.toml to get this implementation (see [list of features](https://crates.io/crates/deadpool-postgres)).

This can be done like this:

```
[dependencies]
deadpool-postgres = { version = "0.10.0", features = ["serde"] }
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!